# Stopping Bootstrap from closing when tapping outside of it wont work

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I've tried :

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
```

And tried adding to the modal div:

```
data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
```

But it wont stop the bootstrap model from closing on outside touch.
I am using IOS safari btw.

I got some input radio on the modal but didnt add them to the code here.

My modal:

```
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal" style="position: fixed;">
            Launch modal
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade hide"  tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                
                    <div id="sportHeader">choose sport:</div>

                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```